# Facebook like box : ''Page could not be reached" Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I created a fb like-box at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

But when I tried to like it, it gives the error as in the attached image. When I clicked on *error* link, it says `The page at https://www.facebook.com/phonekade could not be reached.`

This works fine with my other fb pages. So I can't understand what the problem is. Can anybody help me here? Thanks in advance.

Image: [image: result]

Comment: Are you sure your link is http://www.facebook.com/phonekade?

Comment: yes, as you can see the link works fine.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. Is it a login / credentials issue?

Comment: I get this message: This page can't be seen by the current user. Please check page privacy and visibility settings.

Comment: Sorry, there was a country restriction in page settings. I removed it. (but the issue is still there) I hope you can now view it.

Comment: yes now i can see that, can you change your page with other name for tester?

Comment: what do you mean? if you are asking if this works with other pages, answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the cause it, but it works fine now. I didn't do a thing. May be fb needs time to get things done properly. I created this page yesterday and after a full day it works fine now. Thanks all who tried to help me.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

You should run your page through the Object Debugger. It has some serious problems.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fphonekade

Comment: I don't understand this. Can you please explain? 
It says `You have <meta> tags ouside of your <head>. This is either because your <head> was malformed...`
Which <head> is it talking about?

Comment: You should never have more than one <head> block. If you have more than one, that's another big problem.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to change website url in the facebook code to https instead of http. For some reason after I did that everything worked. Then I changed it back to http and it still worked!

To be clear, I made it:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpagename....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. It works fine for me.

```
<?php }
$url = 'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q='. $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ;
$response = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```